# ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 Console Hosted App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC5, I had a console application that would use Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(...) to host a bunch of controllers that would be dynamically loaded from assemblies placed in an external folder and run some custom initialization on them via API call. This way I could pass parameters to the initialization method that were determined at runtime (and would not be as clunky as maintaining config files).

In MVC6, the self-hosting is now done, as far as I know, by the DNX runtime using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting, but this is all done via command line. Is there a way I can self-host from within a C# console application so I can keep this initialization architecture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Katana's `WebApp` static class has been replaced by `WebHostBuilder`, that offers a much more flexible approach: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs.

You've probably already used this API without realizing it, as it's the component used by the hosting block when you register a new web command in your project.json (e.g `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting server=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener server.urls=http://localhost:54540`) and run it using `dnx` (e.g `dnx . web`):

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const string HostingIniFile = "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini";
        private const string ConfigFileKey = "config";

        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public Program(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Allow the location of the ini file to be specified via a --config command line arg
            var tempBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args);
            var tempConfig = tempBuilder.Build();
            var configFilePath = tempConfig[ConfigFileKey] ?? HostingIniFile;

            var appBasePath = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IApplicationEnvironment>().ApplicationBasePath;
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appBasePath);
            builder.AddIniFile(configFilePath, optional: true);
            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            builder.AddCommandLine(args);
            var config = builder.Build();

            var host = new WebHostBuilder(_serviceProvider, config).Build();
            using (host.Start())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started");
                var appShutdownService = host.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IApplicationShutdown>();
                Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    appShutdownService.RequestShutdown();
                    // Don't terminate the process immediately, wait for the Main thread to exit gracefully.
                    eventArgs.Cancel = true;
                };
                appShutdownService.ShutdownRequested.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Program.cs

Comment: Maybe this code is dated? I am having quite a bit of difficulty with it. For example `WebHostBuilder` seems to have changed its constructors.

Comment: Can i use this with ASP.NET MVC 5 ? (not core)

Answer (score 6):

> ...I had a console application that would use Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(...) to host [and to] pass parameters to the initialization method that were determined at runtime...

**In ASP.NET 4.x** we self-host within a console application using an OWIN host. We run our `MyApp.exe` directly. Its `Main()` method calls `WebApp.Start()` to create the OWIN host. We use an instance of an `IAppBuilder` to build up the HTTP pipeline via `appBuilder.Use()` and chain it all together with `appBuilder.Build()`. This is all within the `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting` namespace.

> Is there a way I can self-host from within a C# console application so I can keep this initialization architecture?

**In ASP.NET Core rc2** we self-host inside a console application using an `IWebHost`. (This is not an OWIN host though OWIN inspired it.) We run our `MyApp.exe` directly. The `Main()` method creates a new `WebHostBuilder()`, which we use to build up the HTTP pipeline via `webHostBuilder.Use()`, chaining it all together with `webHostBuilder.Build()`. This is all within the `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting` namespace.

Regarding Pinpoint's answer, **in ASP.NET Core rc1** we need to run `dnx.exe` instead of running our app directly. The work of the `WebHostBuilder` is hidden inside the `dnx.exe` executable. `Dnx.exe` also starts-up our application.  Our application's `Main()` method calls `WebApplication.Run()`, after which we use an instance of `IApplicationBuilder` to add middleware to the HTTP pipeline via calls to `appBuilder.Use()`. Both our application and `dnx.exe` shared the responsibility of creating/configuring the host. It's convoluted and I am glad that this changed in rc2. I supposed that in rc1 the equivalent of OWIN's `WebApp.Start()` is `WebApplication.Run()`.

```
ASP.NET 4.x            ASP.NET Core rc1           ASP.NET Core rc2

N/A                    Dnx.exe                      N/A
MyApp.exe              MyApp.dll                    MyApp.exe
Main(args)             Main(args)                   Main(args)
WebApp.Start()         WebApplication.Run(args)     N/A   
appBuilder.Use()       appBuilder.Use()             webHostBuilder.Use()
appBuilder.Build()     N/A                          webHostBuilder.Build()
```

Some References

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.hosting.webapp%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Comment: It's important to note, that asp.net 4.x owin hosting only works for webapi which makes it totally useless to you if you want to self host, say an asp.net MVC application.