# Run self-hosted asp.net 5 app programatically

Tags: asp.net, console-application, asp.net-core, self-hosting

I was able to create and run self-hosted asp.net application using command added to `project.json`:
"Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"

**It is possible to run the asp.net app programatically in the same process as console app?**

I have tried

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:5000/");
```

but compiler return errors:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Owin' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   AspNetConsolApp.DNX Core 5.0
>
> CS0103 The name 'WebApp' does not exist in the current context AspNetConsolApp.DNX Core 5.0

my current project.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "System.Diagnostics.Tools": "4.0.0-beta-23109",
     "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting": "2.0.2"
  },

  "commands": {
    "AspNetConsolApp": "AspNetConsolApp",
    "Web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
      "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting": "2.0.2",
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Owin.Hosting": "2.0.2"

      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "System.Diagnostics.Tools": "4.0.0-beta-23109",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, it's possible, and you don't even need OWIN/Katana for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258601/asp-net-5-mvc-6-console-hosted-app/31275082#31275082

Comment: `host.Start()` method throws InvalidOperationException in **IHostingBuilder.UseServer() is required for Start()** When I add line `.UseServer("Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener")`, it throws another InvalidOperationException: No address prefixes were defined, but this time from Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.dl. I'm using beta5 packages

Comment: Ok, I had to add commandline argument `--server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000`.  would like to do this programatically, but that's another issue